# Profiling code with or without optimizations

Tags: c++, c, optimization, profile

Obviously you have to include debug symbols to decode profile session, but do you profile with -O0 or with higher optimization levels? Won't it profile with -O0 be heisenprofiling?

Comment: I would likely run *secondary* profiling passes on the non-optimized builds -- out of curiosity if nothing else. Just keep in mind that it's the *product as distributed* that counts.

Answer (score 3):

You should profile with the optimization settings that you are planning to use in production. It's pointless to do anything else.

Comment: unless you are profiling to count how many time each function is called in a given run. Optimization could inline the function and make it disappear from profiling.

Comment: It's also important to understand that profiling changes the timing of the program under inspection, so there's always a little bit of deviation from an optimised release build.

Comment: I *so* [*disagree*](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/329124/2429) :)

Comment: Here's why: Suppose your code spends a large % of time in *new*, that could be fixed by recycling used objects. Suppose it calls the same function repeatedly with same arguments, and needs memoizing. Suppose it calls a generic system function that, 10 levels down the stack, does some I/O *you* know you don't need. The list goes on and on. Sure, profiling optimized code can steer you away from bottom-feeders if they're your code, but can it shine a brighter light on those *big* issues? All it can do is make them harder to find.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing different code by profiling should be done on the same machine, with the same compiler and with the highest optimization settings. Any other profiles are meaningless.